# Initial Configuration for Android App

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to have some piece of data passed in to the app on the very first app run through via the Google Play link (maybe as an `Intent`).

The scenario I envision is this:

1. I share a special url to my app in the market for special clients (promotion, etc)
2. They download the app, install the app.
3. On the first run, I can pull off the data I put on the url somehow
4. Magic happens

**Current Solution**

My current solution to this problem is sending out a generic link to the market, and have a second url that they click that my app has an `intent-filter`.  I'd really like to have only one url for people to click.

**Thoughts**

An alternative I've considered, is having the link go to my server, save some unique information about the HTTP Request, then try to correlate that information with a web request on the first app run, but that seems very error prone (IP isn't unique on Wi-Fi behind a NAT, User Agents don't match...).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a search for the `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` Intent. [This source](http://gyurigrell.com/2012/2/21/tracking-install-sources-android-apps), for example, says:

> Starting with Android 1.6, the Android Market's emits a broadcast
>   Intent named com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER whenever certain
>   parameters are added to the market url. Note that web version of the
>   Market also passes these parameters to your devices upon install.

I have no idea how up-to-date or well-supported that is, but it sounds like what you want.

Comment: This seems like exactly what I am looking for.  I wrote up a sample app, but I am not getting any calls to my `BroadcastReceiver`.  I will do a little more testing, but from my searching the common hiccups are not configuring your broadcast receiver correctly, or not using an appropriate url and I think I am doing that all correctly.